# How to read a text file using pandas in Python and split each character/letter of the data frame

Tags: python, pandas

How to read a text file using pandas in Python and split each character/letter of the data frame

text_df:

```
7 3
Tno
h%n
a #
tA 
$c 
#T%
ii!
```

And, I want the file to be as below:

```
7   3   
T   n   o
h   %   n
a       #
t   A   
$   c   
#   T   %
i   i   !
```

[image]

Can anyone help me out with this? I tried with the below code but not working out:

```
df = pd.read_csv("location\\text_df.txt", sep='', header=None)
```

Comment: What do you get with your code? Everything in one column? You could try `df[0].str.split(sep="", expand=True)`. But do you really want this in a dataframe, it does not seem like a good data structure to use. What kind of analysis do you plan to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`pd.read_fwf`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_fwf.html)

```
pd.read_fwf('location\\text_df.txt', widths=[1,1,1], header=None)
   0    1    2
0  7  NaN    3
1  T    n    o
2  h    %    n
3  a  NaN    #
4  t    A  NaN
5  $    c  NaN
6  #    T    %
7  i    i    !
```

Or

```
pd.read_fwf('location\\text_df.txt', widths=[1,1,1], header=None).fillna('')
   0  1  2
0  7     3
1  T  n  o
2  h  %  n
3  a     #
4  t  A
5  $  c
6  #  T  %
7  i  i  !
```